# How to make google delete non existings pages from its index using htaccess or php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, http-status-code-404

We had relaunched our online shop but google index saved a lot of old links (>10.000) to the old "product_info.php?item_id=XXX". I thought that google would notice missing links and delete them but our new shop redirects all not existing links to the start page so google think they were all valid and does not delete them from its index!

What should i do to tell google that all links with product_info.php are not valid now, how can i force google delete them all? Should i create a new .htaccess rule or should i place the product_info.php file in my shop directory and write something like  "http_response_code(404);" or 
"header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 404 Not Found', true, 404);" 
inside?

Comment: send a 410 gone header increases remove time from google. Do not prevent Google from craweling those links. Just do that if those content is really not existing anymore. If its on a new location, you should send a 301 header to the new location.

Answer (score 0):

404 header is going to work fine, but it will still take some time for it to disappear from the search results. I would advice using the Remove URLs Tool to speed up the process:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en